# What kind of address give to a socket when establishing tcp connection?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip, ipv6

I have a programme which run the following steps :

Client side :

1. send UDP request (multicast) on a specific port
2. check UDP response
3. extract the address from the response
4. set up socket to the address and the specific port

Server side :

1. receive and check UDP request (multicast) on a specific port
2. send UDP response with its ip address inside.
3. set up socket to the address and the specific port

**My problem is it does not work with ipv6 address :** `fe80:0000:0000:0000:0223:18ff:feed:ef59`

..**but it works with ipv6-mapped ipv4 address** : `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0a40:4caf` (which corresponds to `10.64.76.175`)

According to wikipedia, `10.xxx.xxx.xxx` ipv4 addresses are private class A addresses `fe80::/10` are link local addresses. **Is it the source of my problem ?**

I get these two addresses from the Ethernet interface :

> `ip addr`
>
> ```
>  2 : enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc
> pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
>
> link/ether 00:23:18:ed:ef:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> inet 10.64.76.175/20 brd 10.64.79.255 scope global enp0s25
>    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>
> inet6 fe80::223:18ff:feed:ef59/64 scope link 
>    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
> ```

---

More precisely, the problem comes from this extract : the socket() function sends back an error.

```
int SetupTCPClientSocket(const char *host, const char *service) {
  // Tell the system what kind(s) of address info we want
  struct addrinfo addrCriteria;                   // Criteria for address match
  memset(&addrCriteria, 0, sizeof(addrCriteria)); // Zero out structure
  addrCriteria.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;              // v4 and v6 is OK
  addrCriteria.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;         // Only streaming sockets
  addrCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;         // Only TCP protocol

  // Get address(es)
  struct addrinfo *servAddr; // Holder for returned list of server addrs
  int rtnVal = getaddrinfo(host, service, &addrCriteria, &servAddr);
  if (rtnVal != 0)
    DieWithUserMessage("getaddrinfo() failed", gai_strerror(rtnVal));
  int sock = -1;
  struct addrinfo *addr;
  for (addr = servAddr; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next) 
  {  

    // Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP
    sock = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
      continue;  // Socket creation failed; try next address
    }

    // Establish the connection to the echo server
    if (connect(sock, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == 0)
    {
      break;     // Socket connection succeeded; break and return socket
    }

    close(sock); // Socket connection failed; try next address
    sock = -1;
  }

  freeaddrinfo(servAddr); // Free addrinfo allocated in getaddrinfo()
  return sock;
}
```

Comment: I maybe wrong, but have you checked what is stored in your  struct addrinfo *addr;  on regular output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For link-local addresses (fe80:*) you have to append the interface from which you want to make the connection: `fe80:0000:0000:0000:0223:18ff:feed:ef59%enp0s25`

Comment: I have test a few examples available on the web such as this one : [link](http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2012/12/simple-tcp-client-server-sockets.html). It worked with "::1", but I did not work with "fe80:0000:0000:0000:0223:18ff:feed:ef59" (Invalid argument) nor with "fe80:0000:0000:0000:0223:18ff:feed:ef59%enp0s25" (no such host).

Maybe I have to change some parameters into the network settings. (Firewall is already disable).

Comment: Can you verify, that the interface of the other host ist also called enp0s25?

Comment: Yes, it is, because I am currently working on the same machine.